# Queryset in django admin breaks migrations and py.test

Tags: python, django, django-admin, pytest, django-migrations

I am getting `FATAL: database "xxxxxxxxx" does not exist` during the loading of py.test.  This is coming from the loading of the admin forms, where by I have a queryset being passed to a `ModelChoiceField`

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(SomeModel.objects.limited_qs(), *args, **kwargs)


class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    some_model = CustomChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel


class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SomeModelForm
```

I've tried this with

```
formfield_overrides = { models.ForiegnKey : {'queryset': ... } }
```

all result in the same problem with py.test

**EDIT**

Having the queryset either in the `__init__` method or in `formfield_overrides` also breaks the migrations.

Note: these all work exactly how I want them to on the server - they just prevent me for running any tests.

How do I get this to pass (w/o conditionally registering my admin stuff ;_; I like tdd)

Comment: What's you test code like?

Comment: I have 200 tests, running from integration tests on an API to unit tests on stubbed user models.  The stack trace comes from the ```__init__``` where the queryset is created.  It doesn't even load the tests themselves - just errors out.  The root is ```python3.4/site-packages/_pytest/config.py```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in my case, the problem was that in my SomeModel.objects.limited_qs(), I was calling another queryset like:

```
self.filter(another_model=AnotherModel.objects.get(xxx=1))
```

So, to build the queryset a call to database was executed before the test database creation, causing the "FATAL database does not exist"